# How to properly encode (client) and decode (server) string containing special char such as Non-Breaking Spaces?

Tags: javascript, c#, encoding

I need to safely transmit strings that may contain non-breaking spaces ([NBSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), Unicode U+00A0) through security filters like Cloudflare's.
Additionally, I'm looking for a method to potentially reduce the payload size for efficiency.
The challenge is to ensure these strings not losing their original structure.

Here is the client:

```
var encoded = window.btoa(encodeURIComponent("SELECT a FROM b"));
//U0VMRUNUJUMyJUEwYSVDMiVBMEZST00lQzIlQTBi
```

While in reality the "SELECT a FROM b" is "SELECT`NBSF`a`NBSF`FROM`NBSF`b".

And the server side code reproduce this string: `SELECT%C2%A0a%C2%A0FROM%C2%A0b` while the final should string should the same "SELECT a FROM b".

```
var valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(valueBytes);
```

How can I modify my server-side code to correctly decode the percent-encoded NBSP (and potentially other characters) back into their original form?
Is there a more efficient way to reduce the payload size? (this is less important)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `Uri.UnescapeDataString`:

```
var valueBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
var decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(valueBytes);
return Uri.UnescapeDataString(decodedString);
```